# Show grouped record count in group heading on tcxgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I have a form with a cxgrid on it and I have allowed grouping on the grid.

When I drag and drop column into the group section, instead of it just displaying the column name, is there a way for it to also include the record count for that grouping?

example of group:

[image]

Status is a column on the grid which has multiple statuses. So after Active/Closed it would have the record count for that status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Object Inspector

- click your cxGridDBTableView1
- in the Summary sub-property, click the button to the right of DefaultGroupSummaryItem
- in the pop-up set Kind to skCount

That's it.

To a certain extent, you can customize how the Summary (group) rows are displayed by adjusting properties in the OI.  It that isn't sufficient, you can I believe draw the group cells yourself in the

```
cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawGroupCell
```

event.  But that would involve finding your way around the objects passed to it, in particular the AViewInfo object.